# Difference between Key Material and actual Key

Tags: java, cryptography

I am confused about what Key Material is when generating keys using Java libraries,

According to SecretKeySpec documentation,

```
public byte[] getEncoded()
```

> Returns the key material of this secret key.

What exactly key material is ? , because if I try to print any key like this,

```
System.out.print(secretKey.getEncoded())
```

I get weird output like,

```
s[B@541187f9
```

but when I print it using any Encoding scheme, like Base64, Base16, I get the actual key.

Could any one explain what key material really is ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SecretKeySpec is used for symmetric algorithms. Those algorithms have only one key which is a bit string. In Java it is represented as a byte array (`byte[]`). The encodings of asymmetric algorithm keys are [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353748/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-privatekey-or-publickey-type).

```
byte[] keyBytes = /* set the key somehow */;
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
Arrays.equals(keyBytes, keySpec.getEncoded()); // true
```

As for the "weird" output, arrays are not printable in Java so only the reference is printed. If you even wanted to specifically print the `byte[]` this would also not work, because generally text should only use characters that are printable. That is why encoding it as Base64 lets you print the key, but also inflates the key.

In the documentation they probably talk about key *material*, because it returns the actual key bytes without additional information such as algorithm that the key corresponds to.